# Convert HTML from stored in variable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, console-application

I have a c# application that recieves HTML POST data. Now how do I take form data that was stored in variable?

This is what gets stored from the post data

```
------------------------------0123abcdefab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"


------------------------------0123abcdefab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="snapshot.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

???? JFIF      ?? C         

------------------------------0123abcdefab--
```

notice how both form fields are stored as one in a string variable.
how do i split this into 2 separate variables?

also how do i store the image form data in a variable so it can still be written as a image?

Comment: What framework are you using? MVC? ASP Pages? Web API? Something custom?

Comment: c# .net 4.0 console app

Answer (score 0):

As I read from your comments, you're not using ASP.NET. Therefore you'll have to learn the HTTP protocol.

In the header list, you'll find the `Content-Type` header, the value contains "boundary" key. Its value is the part from where you split each file, or input, and process each of them one by one.

However, I strongly recommend you to look into ASP.NET WebAPI. It's platform independent and thus you can use it with your console application.